# why safari, ie and yandex doesn't load blank page instead of react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, safari, browserstack

here i have a react app that has some codes like **[finally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)** that is not supported in some browsers like IE, Safari and ... (i tested it in **[BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)**)

as you can see it doesn't show anything on IE:[image]
and here we can see the project on firefox[image]

can some one help me to run these codes on unsupported browsers because i really can't change the code it will be so hard to correct it

do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You should check list of compatible browser list from bottom of page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Comment: As you can see, `finally()` is not supported by IE 11. You need to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to support it in IE. You can refer to the solution in [this thread](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8111). If there're other functions you using which are not supported by IE 11, you also need to use some polyfills to transpile the code.